# Django, better many 2 many in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

is there anyway to improve this in the django admin panel?

As you can see its a simple Many2Many field.

I would like to access that record with a simple mouse click.

[image]

Comment: what exactly you desire and what have you done so far to achieve it?

Comment: Have you looked at the screenshot? @Gahan – I want to click that m2m record and automatically access it in the admin view.

Comment: "click that m2m record and automatically access it " define.. access it.. what you want to do on click?

Comment: see it in the admin view, open a page with that object, you name it. @Gahan

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom HTML into the admin as a field if you define the content in a method:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['related_thing_links', ...]
    readonly_fields = ['related_thing_links']

    def related_thing_links(self, obj):
        items = []
        for thing in obj.related_things.all():
            url = reverse(
                'admin:myapp_relatedthing_change',
                kwargs={'pk': thing.pk}
            )
            items.append(format_html(
                '<li><a href="{url}">{thing}</a></li>',
                url=url,
                thing=thing,
            ))
        return mark_safe('<ul>' + ' '.join(items) + '</ul>')
    related_thing_links.short_description = 'related things'
```

I've not managed to test this exactly, but it's based on working code.